# How to iterate correct through the widgets in a QMdiArea?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some problem figuring out, how to iterate horugh the widgets I added to a QMdiArea. When I add a QWidget to a QMdiArea and then iterating through with follwing code, I get two different pointers for my widget, where the pointers while iterating are incorrect:

```
    QWidget* w1 = new QWidget();
    QWidget* w2 = new QWidget();
    qDebug() << w1;
    qDebug() << w2;
    QMdiArea* mdi = new QMdiArea();
    mdi->addSubWindow(w1);
    mdi->addSubWindow(w2);

    foreach(QWidget* widget, mdi->subWindowList()) {
        qDebug() << widget;
    }
```

Sample output:

```
QWidget(0x21f0610)
QWidget(0x21f0680)
QMdiSubWindow(0x21f07d0)
QMdiSubWindow(0x2195420)
```

How can I get the correct pointers from the MdiArea? Thanks!

Comment: What means "correct pointers"? Why your results are incorrect?

Comment: @vahancho, I want the pointers of the QWidget, not the pointers of the QMdiSubWindow

Comment: Are you sure about your code? This `foreach (QWidget* widget, mdi->subWindowList())` even doesn't compile for me. It should be `foreach(QMdiSubWindow* widget, mdi->subWindowList())` instead.

Comment: looks like the widgets are wrapped in a QMdiSubWindow, did you try `foreach(QMdiSubWindow* sub, mdi->subWindowList()) {
        qDebug() << sub->widget();
    }`

Comment: @vahancho it compiled for me on windows 7 with Qt5.9.1 and Visual c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc Ströbel was right:
Following code provided the correct pointers. I wasn't aware that the QMdiArea creates a QMdiSubWindow and wraps my widget:

```
QWidget* w1 = new QWidget();
QWidget* w2 = new QWidget();
qDebug() << w1;
qDebug() << w2;
QMdiArea* mdi = new QMdiArea();
mdi->addSubWindow(w1);
mdi->addSubWindow(w2);

foreach(QMdiSubWindow* sub, mdi->subWindowList()) {
    qDebug() << sub;
    qDebug() << sub->widget();
}
```

Sample output:

```
QWidget(0x21c0610)
QWidget(0x21c0680)
QMdiSubWindow(0x21c07d0)
QWidget(0x21c0610)
QMdiSubWindow(0x2165420)
QWidget(0x21c0680)
```